# Add/Sub hours to my Calendar object

Tags: java, calendar

I am using **Calendar class** in my project. In some cases, I need to subtract some hours to a date. I can face this easily.

The problem is **when I subtract hours and it changes the day** (one or more days later).

How can I manage it?

Thank you in advance,
Diego.

Comment: What specifically is the problem? Without more details, we can't really assist you.

Comment: Please post some code.

Comment: Why do you not want the days to be changed when adding or subtracting hours (or have I misunderstood you)? What is the use case?

Answer (score 0):

The `Calendar` has the `add()` and `roll()` methods:

> `add(int field, in amount)`: Adds or subtracts the specified amount of time to the given calendar field, based on the calendar's rules.
>
> `roll(int field, in amount)`: Adds the specified (signed) amount to the specified calendar field **without changing larger fields**.

So if you want to add 2 hours to Monday, 23:00 and get Tuesday, 01:00 do:

```
calendar.add(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 2);
```

If you want to get Monday 01:00 do:

```
calendar.roll(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 2);
```

Comment: Sorry for my late, @Nikos Paraskevopoulos
I have checked your answer and it doesn't work for me. My code is something like this:
Calendar now = Calendar.getInstance(t); int hours = 65;
now.add(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, horas);

Now is a Calendar instance. Well, if you throw this code, you dont get 2 days in the future (because of 65 hours...), I just get 65 hours more... :(

Answer (score 0):

I believe that using the normal add() method from Calendar you can be in control of the hours to be subtracted, considering the passing of one or more days. Please see this example that removes 5 days and 3 hours:

```
public void changeDate() {

    SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("d MMM yyyy hh:mm aaa");
    Calendar calendar = new GregorianCalendar(2013, Calendar.MARCH, 12);
    String date1 = sdf.format(calendar.getTime());
    System.out.println("Date1: "+date1); 

    //Remove 2 days and 2 hours
    calendar.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, -2);
    calendar.add(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, -2);


    String date2 = sdf.format(calendar.getTime());
    System.out.println("Date2: "+date2);

}
```

If you want to remove an hour but prevent the day to change then use the roll() method instead